Non-cyclic inequality with fractions
I need help with following inequality problem:
Let
$a,b,c$ are positive real numbers $\mathbb{R}^+$. Prove that
$$
\frac{2}{a^2}+\frac{5}{b^2}+\frac{45}{c^2}>\frac{16}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{24}{(b+c)^2}+\frac{48}{(a+c)^2}.
$$
I was unable to find any classical inequality trick (AM-GM inequality, Cauchy-Schwarz…) which could work since the inequality is non-cyclic because of the numerators.
I tried to use trivial fact $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^+$:
$$
\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}>\frac{2}{(x+y)^2}
$$
to create separate inequalities:
$$
\frac{2}{a^2}+\frac{2}{b^2}>\frac{4}{(a+b)^2}
$$
$$
\frac{3}{b^2}+\frac{3}{c^2}>\frac{6}{(b+c)^2}
$$
but they not add up together to the desired form since term $\frac{42}{c^2}$  left on the left hand side and many others on the right hand side.
Clearing denominators (multiply everything) probably does not work since
it leads to very complicated form.
I found out that numerators $24, 48$ are one less than perfect square ($24=5^2-1$, same for $48$) so I tried to use completing the square method but I did not succeed.

You're really close. Here are some more observations to guide what you're thinking. 1/ Your trivial fact is way off. You'd want something like $\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{y^2} \geq \frac{8}{(x+y)^2}$.  Hey, 8 on RHS! 2/ (Near-)Equality doesn't occur anywhere close to $k(1, 1, 1)$, whereas that's what your listed inequalities use. So those aren't what we really want. 3/ We'd likely want something like $ \frac{1}{x^2 } + \frac{ n}{y^2} \geq \frac{m } { (x+y)^2 } $. How do $n, m$ relate? When does equality hold? $\quad$ Combining with your existing ideas, it's possible to push this through.

@CalvinLin I conjectured that this inequality for $n \in \mathbb{N}, x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ holds: $\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{n}{y^2}\geq \frac{3n+5}{(x+y)^2}$, but I do not know how to prove it after multiplying everything - I can not find nice factorization.

After applying previous inequality for $n=14$ with $a,c$ and for $n=6$ with $b,c$ I get more promising inequality $(\frac{1}{a})^2+(\frac{2}{b})^2+(\frac{5}{c})^2>(\frac{4}{a+b})^2+(\frac{1}{b+c})^2+(\frac{1}{a+c})^2$ since only perfect squares are involved but I do not know how to prove it as well.

1/  I verified that your inequality is correct, likewise by expansion . 2/ Given that, you do have the desired inequality. Can you show me how you were combining them? I do not get your LHS nor RHS.

Prove the following. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried.

I encourage you to guess what the 3 separate inequalities that we want are, before reading further. The RHS is pretty determined, so it's a matter of how to combine the coefficients on the LHS.

$\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{y^2} \geq \frac{8}{(x+y)^2} $.

In particular, find a proof via one-application of the power mean inequality.
Equality holds when $x=y$.


$\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{n^2}{y^2} \geq \frac{8n}{(x+y)^2} $.

Equality holds only when $n = \frac{y}{x} = 1$.
My proof is essentially by expanding all terms, smartly.


Using 3 inequalities for a suitable $n$ (see the RHS), arrive at the desired conclusion.

We have strict inequality as we use $n \neq 1$.
It is quite a weak bound, so there are likely other approaches. EG OP claims that $\frac{1}{x^2}  + \frac{4}{y^2} \geq \frac{ 17}{(x+y)^2}$ which I've verified, whereas I'm only using $\frac{1}{x^2}  + \frac{4}{y^2} \geq \frac{ 16}{(x+y)^2}$



